# Submit a form inside a modal as soon as my user press Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to submit a form inside a modal as soon as user press `enter` key.

I have tried the following

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('modal is opened ! ');
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            console.log('Enter Pressed !');
            var form = $('.modal').find('.modal-dialog').closest('form')
                .find('button[type=submit]').click();

            console.log(form);
        }
    });
})
```

---

I got the console to print out

```
modal is opened ! 
Enter Pressed !
prevObject: e.fn.init[0], context: document, selector: "button[type=submit]"]
```

---

## Try #2

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('modal is opened ! ');
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            console.log('Enter Press');
            var form = $('.modal').find('.modal-dialog').closest('form').submit();
            console.log(form);
        }
    });
})
```

**Console**

```
modal is opened ! 
Enter Press
[prevObject: e.fn.init[3], context: document]
```

Form is still not submitting ... for some reasons.

---

I know I am pretty close, but I couldn't get the my form to submit.

Can someone please give me a little push here ?

[image]

Comment: use form.submit();

Comment: Do you handle submission with AJAX?

Comment: Downvoter, what's wrong with this question?

Comment: @Mojtaba : Yes, what did I do wrong to deserve that ?

Comment: @ihue, I guess some people used to downvote if they saw any image inside the question. By the way, I think your question is clear enough and no need to any images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to find the submit button.

```
$('.modal').find('.modal-dialog').closest('form').submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`$('.modal').find('.modal-dialog').closest('form').submit()`

Comment: Exactly the same answer I posted before :)

Comment: Mojtaba, you are very smart!

Comment: And you are a great duplicator. So, even more smart